# Solving Least Squares with Linear Inequality Constraints in Python

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, constraints, least-squares

I am trying to solve a least squares problem subject to a linear system of inequality constraints in Python. I have been able to solve this problem in MatLab, but for the project I am working in all of our code-base should be in Python, so I am looking for an equivalent way to solve it, but have been unable to.

Some background on the problem:

I have images with pixel values in their raw digital number (DN) form, and I want to come up with a regression line that models the linear relationship between the DNs and the true reflectance values of the surfaces in my image.

I have 6 known reflectances and corresponding DNs, and so I make a linear system of equations:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[1, 19039],[1, 47792], [1, 9672], [1, 32521], [1, 11409], [1, 58843]])
b = np.array([[0.05938044], [0.27213514], [0.00252875], [0.18535543], [0.01959069], [0.52605937]])
b = np.squeeze(b)
```

I set up the objective function to be the 2-norm of (Ax-b)*0.5

```
def f(, x):
    # function to minimize
    y = np.dot(A, x) - b
    return (np.dot(y, y))*.5
```

Then I want to add my constraints. Since surface reflectance values are bounded between 0-1, I want to ensure that the minimum DN value within my image has a reflectance value greater than 0 when converted from DN to reflectance through the estimates slope and intercept coefficients, and that the maximum DN value of the image is mapped to a reflectance of below or equal to 1.

According to the [paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8353392) that I am implementing, I can split the requirement of `0 <= slope*DN + intercept <= 1` into two parts:

```
slope*DN_max + intercept <= 1

-slope*DN_min - intercept <= 0
```

Thus, I create two matrices, one containing the minimum DN value and the intercept coefficient (1), and one containing the maximum DN value and the intercept coefficient (1). I make these into matrices, because in practice I would have more than one image being calibrated and thus I would have more than two columns and two rows (I would have n by n*2 matrices, where n = number of images), but for this simplified example I will just work with one image.

```
img_min = 0
img_max = 65536
C_min = np.array([[-1, img_min]])
C_max = np.array([[1, img_max]])

def cons_min(x):
    # constraint function for the minimum pixel values
    return np.array((C_min @ x))

def cons_max(x):
    # constraint function for the maximum pixel values
    return np.array((C_max @ x))-1
```

Then I tried to use optimize.minimize to solve for the coefficients.

```
con1 = [{'type': 'ineq', 'fun': cons_min},
        {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': cons_max}
       ]
initial = [0, 0]
result = optimize.minimize(f, 
                           initial, 
                           method='SLSQP', 
                           constraints=con1
                           )
```

In MatLab using the `lsqlin(A,B, C, c)` function the result I get is

```
intercept = 0.0000000043711483450798073327817072630808
slope = 0.0000069505505573854644717126521902273
```

[image: Result with MatLab]

But using the optimize.minimize function I get

```
[-2.80380803e-17,  1.52590219e-05]
```

where the first value of the list is the intercept and the second is the slope.
[image: Result with Python]

I think perhaps it is a problem with the constraints I am setting, but I have tried to play around with them and it hasn't improved the result in any way.

Is there a better way of solving this problem in Python? Or is there something I can improve in my current approach?

Thanks.

Comment: I would not be surprised to see that this is a scaling-problem. SLSQP is just too general (NLP) and too unrobust (compared to more specialized approaches; ah and you are doing numerical diff too) which might completely fail when the decision variables are expected to be in range 10e-5 - 10e-8. This might actually even be the range of it's first-order stopping criterions. Solver-status might indicate such problems. Apart from that, scipy might not be my first pick here as it's limited in this regard. A more potent hack would be pyomo + ipopt (but even this is less specialized than possible).

Comment: Imho you want a convex qp-solver or socp-solver (both based on interior-point methods). Sadly, there is not much good software available (when restricted by licenses or wrappers). Except you are doing (license-compatible) academic work: then just use CPLEX, Gurobi or Mosek. **Edit** you could also describe this with *few lines of code* in [cvxpy](https://www.cvxpy.org/) and try ECOS (most accurate), OSQP or SCS (both less accurate). Scaling might still be needed. Also: if this approach fails (with ECOS), chances grow that you got some *other problems* (then solvers) as the solver is quite good

Comment: Thanks for the tips! It ended up working by using cvxpy and the ECOS solver! The set-up for cvxpy with the constraints was also much more straightforward than it was using scipy, so I am quite happy with this approach! If you want to make your comment into an answer then I will gladly mark it as a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the advice from sascha in the comments, I have managed to arrive at a solution:

```
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1, 19039],[1, 47792], [1, 9672], [1, 32521], [1, 11409], [1, 58843]])
b = np.array([[0.05938044], [0.27213514], [0.00252875], [0.18535543], [0.01959069], [0.52605937]])
b = np.squeeze(b)
C_min = np.array([[-1, 0]])
C_max = np.array([[1, 65535]])

x = cp.Variable(A.shape[1])

objective = cp.Minimize(0.5 * cp.sum_squares(A@x-b))
constraints = [C_min@x <= 0, C_max@x <= 1]

prob = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)
result = prob.solve(solver=cp.ECOS)

intercept = x.value[0]
slope = x.value[1]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(A[:, 1], b)
plt.plot(A[:, 1], np.multiply(A[:, 1], slope) + intercept)
```

Which gives me the best fit line based on my constraints

[image]

And if I check and compare the residuals between the original MatLab solution and the cvxpy solution, I see that the cvxpy solution is ever so slightly better in this example (although very minimal).

```
# MatLab estimated values for the slope and intercept
ML_inter = 0.0000000043711483450798073327817072630808
ML_slope = 0.0000069505505573854644717126521902273

# get the residuals for each data point
c_res = []
ml_res = []
for i in range(A.shape[0]):
    residual = (np.multiply(A[i, 1], x.value[1]) + x.value[0]) - b[i]
    c_res.append(residual)
    residual = (np.multiply(A[i, 1], ML_slope) + ML_inter) - b[i]
    ml_res.append(residual)

# calculate the sum of squares
ss_cvx = np.sum(np.array(c_res)**2)
ss_ml = np.sum(np.array(ml_res)**2)

print("Sum of squares for cvx:    ", ss_cvx)
print("Sum of squares for matlab: ", ss_ml)
print("Sum of squares is lower for CVX solution? ", ss_cvx < ss_ml)

# Sum of squares for cvx:     0.03203817995131549
# Sum of squares for matlab:  0.032038181467959566
# Sum of squares is lower for CVX solution?  True
```